# No bootable device after fresh installation

Tags: grub2, system-installation, lubuntu, boot-repair

So I'm trying to revive an old pc for a project. It's really lowspec so I tried to put Lubuntu on it, but couldn't boot after installation.
I tried running boot-repair but it too failed. Here's the pastebin:
https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/Ys3dxZC49w/
Any help is appreciated!

Comment: It says PC card. Is that an external one not a MMC device that is internal? Some system will not boot from PC cards. But it may boot if you plug into an USB adapter so seen as a USB flash drive. But if really old it may not boot from flash drive either.

Comment: Your pasted info also mentions an unknown MBR; some machines have BIOS/UEFI settings that disable write to MBR for security reasons (ie. you must go into bios/uefi to turn that off to install a new OS) so I'd check your BIOS/UEFI security settings.

Comment: Thank you so much for the advice, but in the meantime, I tried to install Windows XP and uppon inserting the USB with it, it recognized that grub is indeed installed and gave me the option to FINALLY boot into Lubuntu. Anyway, even after restarting it everything works fine now so I won't mess with it! Weird XP magic...